# Going from Infinite Continued Fraction to real numbers

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

I have been given the infinite continued fraction of $\left[12, 2, 2, 12,\dots\right]$ where the first 12 is the natural number part and the remaining numbers repeat. I am familiar with how to convert real numbers into continued fractions, but I am stuck as to how to convert a continued fraction into a real number. I know that since this is infinite, it must be a irrational number, so it must be a $\sqrt{n}$ or $a + \sqrt{n}$. What is a good way to start approaching this question? Thank you.

Comment: Start with a simpler example like $[1; 2, 2, 2, \ldots]$.  If you call this $x$ then by partially writing out the definition of the continued fraction you can see that $x = 1 / (1 + [1; 2, 2, 2, \ldots]) = 1/(1+x)$.  Solving this gives you a quadratic equation in $x$ which lets you narrow it down to one of two possibilities.  You can further decide which of the two is $x$ by bounding the value of $x$ (for instance, it's easy to see in this case that $1 < x < 2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Call the value $x$. Subtract $12$, invert, subtract $2$, invert, subtract $2$, and invert. You get $x$ back again.

Write this down and solve for $x$.

$$x = \frac1{\frac1{\frac1{x-12}-2}-2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (I'm not sure if your first comma was intended to be a semicolon; in any event, you can modify slightly if your notation represents something different from the equations below, but the method is roughly the same):

If I am understanding your notation correctly, then you are considering the continued fraction:

[image]

Because of the repetition, this could be rewritten as:

[image]

Now, you have an equation with one variable. In trying to solve for $x$, you will come to see that this is a quadratic equation; thus, two possible solutions will arise. However, one of them will be negative and the other one will be positive. Since your constructed number is manifestly positive, you'll want the latter.

Comment: You could really use some math latex to normalize the fonts ^_^

Comment: @GaurangTandon Be the change.

Comment: I guess I'm better off being lazy :P

Comment: @GaurangTandon I'm not convinced $\LaTeX$ would make this more readable. Although, I *did* write "$x$" in the final paragraph...

Comment: Fine, I am very much used to only seeing latex math on this site. So, this handdrawn image of maths came as a surprise.